# In Magento 1 Sales menu add custom created sub-menu

Tags: magento-1, menu, sales

In Magento 1 Sales menu list add one new sub-menu same as order or invoice.

Any one can create this type of extension?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom extension or add the appropriate node to the `adminhtml.xml` file or into the `config.xml` file (*if the version of your Magento less than 1.4*) of existing extension.

Creation of the extension (**Module_Name**):
1) please create new *XML* file (**Module_Name.xml**) in the following directory:

> Magento_root/app/etc/modules/

with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Module_Name>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Module_Name>
    </modules>
</config>
```

2) please create new *XML* file (**adminhtml.xml**) in the following directory:

> Magento_root/app/code/community/Module/Name/etc/

with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <sales>
            <children>
                <modulename translate="title">
                    <title>Module Name</title>
                    <action>adminhtml/modulename</action>
                    <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                </modulename>
            </children>
        </sales>
    </menu>
</config>
```

For the `config.xml` file, the **menu** node should be in the **adminhtml** node:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
```

You can play with the `sort_order` to place a menu item to the needed place of *Sales* menu.